Distributive Lattices, proper filters and prime filters
I am trying to prove the proposition : Let $L$ be a distributive lattice and $G$ a proper filter of L. Prove $G$ is intersection of prime filters .
I know that Monteiro proved this, but I cant find the proof anywhere. This is my work :
Let $L$ be a distributive lattice, $P$ prime filters of $L$ and $G$ a proper filter of $L$.
Define $\Sigma$ = { $P$ : $G \subseteq P $}. I showed this set is non empty.
And now I have to show that $G = \cap{P_i}_{P_i \in \Sigma}$
The part of $G \subseteq \cap{P_i}_{P_i \in \Sigma}$ seems trivial.
I am having trouble with  $\cap{P_i}_{P_i \in \Sigma} \subseteq G $. I don’t see how to prove it.
This is where I need help. Can someone show me how to prove it? Or give me some hints?

Hint: If $L$ is a distributive lattice and $G$ is a filter and $I$ an ideal on $L$ with $G\cap I=\varnothing$ then it can be proved that a prime filter $P$ exists with $G\subseteq P$ and $P\cap I=\varnothing$. For every $x\notin G$ we can apply this on the principal ideal $I_x$ on $x$. For proving this order the collection of filters that contain $G$ and have empty intersection with $I$ by inclusion and prove by Zorns lemma that there is a maximal element. This maximal element can be shown to be a prime filter.
